# How to use JSON Model Property as path for OData v4 List Binding in UI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I try to display a list of objects from an OData V4 service in SAP UI5. I would like to use a property from a JSON Model to set the binding path for the list items.

I thought I can just set the path in the items aggregation of the table:

```
<Table
  items="{
    path: '{appView>/dataPath}',
    parameters: {
      $count: true,
      $$updateGroupId: 'peopleGroup'
    }
  }">...</Table>
```

and of course define and set the model:

```
var oViewModel = new JSONModel({
  dataPath: "/People"
});

this.getView().setModel(oViewModel, "appView");
```

For some reason the data is not loaded. There is not even items binded to the table:

```
oTable.getBinding("items");  // undefined
```

The JSON Model is defined in the init method of the controller.

Anybody has an idea why this is not working?

Comment: would suggest binding oData directly on the Table. You are creating an empty new JSONModel anyway

Comment: The reason why I want to do this is that this view is used for two different entities. So depending on the source I want to bind different paths to this table.

Comment: can you add the information where you retrieve the oData call or where you get any data?

Comment: The OData Model is created as the default model in the manifest.json. Therefore the binding '/People'  fetches the data from the OData Service.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you want to bind path dynamically.in such case you can write template in xml without any path then in controller you have write bind path 
XML View:

```
<Table id="tblData" items="{}"> <items> **template code ** </items> </Table>
```

Controller:

```
var oTable = this.getView().byId("tblData"),
    sPath = this.getModel("appView").getProperty("/dataPath"),
    oBinding = oTable.bindItems({path: sPath});
```

for filters:

```
oBinding.filter(aFilters);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> items: "{
>   path: '{appView>/dataPath}',
> ```
>
> Anybody has an idea why this is not working?

Binding definitions apply **only for ManagedObject's properties and aggregations.** As `path` is just a plain object property, trying to bind anything there will be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to bind the Table to the *result* of the `{appView>/dataPath}` binding, I think you need to use [Expression Binding](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/5cff8d1c3fb84c5db7a00f2daca125af) to solve this.

```
items="{
    path: '{= ${appView>/dataPath}}',
    parameters: {
      $count: true,
      $$updateGroupId: 'peopleGroup'
    }
```

Comment: This also is not working. I begin to think that bindings are just not supported here